# input field immediately executes any written js code

Tags: angularjs, xss

We have a text input which is binded to a variable in angular controller.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="activityTypeStatement.InformationText" />
```

There are no other bindings, no `ng-watch` on controller but whenever I paste or write some js code inside it, it executes immediately without any submitting needed. And this is a possible XSS vulnerability which I'm trying to solve.

Scenarios where code executed;

Pasting `<script>alert(1)</script>`

Typing `<script>alert(1)` (executes before closing tag, which I found suspicious)

Typing `alert(1)` first and then adding `<script>` before it

I thought about setting an ng-watch to the input and using ng-sanitize on the input value but since it executes without submitting, I'm not sure if it works.

Only mention of InformationText at the controller is in a object declaration.

How can I make sure inputs into this field would not cause XSS attacks?

Comment: Why would the script execute? Post a complete minimal example (in a plunkr for example) reproducing the problem. I tried, but it doesn't reproduce the problem: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/2xO88tsllURkaAKQ?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

Comment: I don't know how to use Plunkr, I'll try to set up a working example

Comment: It really should not execute any code. You should show more of your code, otherwise it will be difficult to pinpoint what is causing this issue